# Converting an Integer Value into Multiple Strings?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

So I am writing a basic Tower of Hanoi program for my Algorithms class and I just reread the instructions and it wants me to display each Towers' contents after each step (Ex. A = 4,3,2,1) with 4 being the bottom disc in Tower A and 1 being the topmost.  I already have the following code written for the program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {


public static void main(String[]args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    int discs;
    System.out.println("How many discs are in the starting tower? ");
    discs = keyboard.nextInt();
    keyboard.close();
    Hanoi(discs, 'A', 'B', 'C');
}

public static void Hanoi(int n, char Tower1, char Tower2, char Tower3){
    if (n>0) {
        Hanoi(n-1, Tower1, Tower2, Tower3);

        if(n%2 == 0){
        System.out.println("Move disc from " + Tower1 + " to " + Tower2);
        System.out.println("Move disc from " + Tower1 + " to " + Tower3);
        System.out.println("Move disc from " + Tower2 + " to " + Tower3);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Move disc from " + Tower1 + " to " + Tower3);
            System.out.println("Move disc from " + Tower1 + " to " + Tower2);
            System.out.println("Move disc from " + Tower3 + " to " + Tower2);
        }
    }
}
```

Possibly a few brackets are missing due to having other code not pertaining to this.

My question is whether or not I can take the value of n/discs (from the code) and convert it to individual digits to populate multiple arrays for the output like so:

Example: n = 4
Array [4,3,2,1]  (Tower1)

and be able to move these values around as the tower game would have you do

I like the code I have and as a lower level programmer would like to not have to delete it but I am willing to listen to whoever can help me out.

Comment: All you want to do is convert characters to numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's being asked, but it's simple to convert characters to integers. You can just use a switch statement or add a number to the character's int value. You may want to make some adjustments to the actual Hanoi algorithm, it's usually done with two recursive calls. (See [Hanoi tutorial](https://www.learneroo.com/modules/71/nodes/402)).